# facing difficulty to Control a visible div will be hide and hidden div will be visible using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two div one is visible and another is hide. on click visible div will be hide and invisible div will be visible the code are as follows:

CSS

```
.hide_div{
visibility:hidden;
}
.show_div{
visibility:visible
}
```

Jquery:

```
function hideandshow(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#hide').is(':visible')) {  
    $("#hide").removeClass('show_div');
    $("#hide").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    };
    if ($('#show').is(':hidden')) {  
    $("#show").removeClass('hide_div');
    $("#show").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    };
    };
```

HTML

```
<div id="hide"><input type="text" name="id" value="1" onclick="hideandshow()" /></div>
    <div id="Show" class="hide_div"><input type="text" name="id" value="3" /></div>
```

Please help me how to solve this difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using css properties use jQuery methods `show()` and `hide()` like,

```
$('#hide').click(function(){
    if ($('#hide').is(':visible')) {  
        $("#hide").hide();
    };
    if ($('#Show').is(':hidden')) {  
        $("#Show").show();
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="hide"><input type="text" name="id" value="1" /></div>
<div id="show" style="display: none;"><input type="text" name="id" value="3" /></div>
```

Also your code doesn't look syntactically correct, you haven't closed the `$(document).ready()` properly and it is inside other function. Also you haven't mentioned in your question to which element you want to bind the onclick event.

**UPDATE**

You have a typo in your code, your div id is 'Show' and you are using 'show' in your selector,

```
$("#show").css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/abeLL87d/16/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: as `:visible` selector does not work here because Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, Check this link [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and same thing apply to [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
if ($('#hide').css('visibility') == 'visible') { 
    $("#hide").removeClass('show_div');
    $("#hide").css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
}

if ($('#Show').css('visibility') == 'hidden') { 
    $("#Show").removeClass('hide_div');
    $("#Show").css('visibility', 'visible'); 
}
```

And you function definition not need to enclose with $(document).ready

Comment: using above code visible div is hidden but at the same time hidden div not visible. Please tell me more....

Comment: Make sure your id selector are same as element id attribute, as I have used `#show` but in your example s should be capital ie instead of `#show`, it should be `#Show`